# How to create UIAlertView with multiple options?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I am trying to work out how I can use a UIAlertView to do more than one command.

Basically, in my ViewController, there is already an alertView, however I am now adding some storekit files, which, require there own alertView (to tell it whether to purchase the in-app or cancel etc.

Here is original alertView code;

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        [g_GameUtils removeAlbumFolder:deleteIndex];
        [g_GameUtils readAllData];
        [g_GameUtils getAlbumFolderList];
        [m_pTable reloadData];
    }
}
```

And here is what I need also - they are both called alertView so I cannot use both like this, is there a way to combine them? Or is it better to call one of them alertView2 ? If so, how does it know which one to call for the particular alert?

Thanks in advance!

Chris

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0){
        //cancel button clicked. Do something here or nothing here
    }
    else{
        //other button indexes clicked
        [[MKStoreManager sharedManager] buyFeature:@"com.davis.apptoken.buy"];
    }

}
```

Comment: do you have references e.g self.alertView and self.alertView2, if yes you can just compare if(alertView == self.alertView) etc or isEqual:

Comment: Hi, no I do not have references, is there an easy way to do this? Many thanks, Chris

Comment: I suppose you can set different button's indexes... f.e from 1 to 3 for first alertView and from 4 to 6 for second one... 0 for cancel button.

Comment: @InjectIOS No, you can't set the button indexes like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can use alertView.tag = 1; and alertView2.tag = 2; and add appropriate conditions to delegate:

```
if (alertView.tag == 1) 
{
    // First alert 
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I am still struggling :)

Comment: Before the `[yourAlertView release]` tag it with `yourAlertView.tag = 1;`. Then in `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:`, do `if (alertView.tag == 1){if (buttonIndex == 0) {//Button 0 of alertView tagged 0 pressed}}...`